# Displayed in Browser different when logged in. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, view, partial

I'm new to rails:

I've created a Reddit-lite like site. After I uploaded it to heroku I noticed that when I was signed in to an account I created on the site, the page was displayed in the browser as I intended it to be displayed, but when I logged out, or even before I logged in, the partial was displayed much larger than I intended it to be.

I've tried putting in search terms to here and haven't found anything close to the issue I am having, so I assume I am not describing it incorrectly. Here is a link to my site, so where ever I am lacking in describing my issue might be overcome by your experiencing it.

http://postit-reed.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The h3 tag around your welcome message isn't closed properly when logged out. Causing the browser to wrap the rest of your html in the h3 which applies a bigger font size to everything making it look bigger. Fix the h3 tag.